# How do I create whitespace between tables?

Tags: css

I have two tables and just need a gap between the two to make it look nicer. How do I do that?

This is how the tables are laid out so far:

```
<html><body>
  <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
</body></html>
```

This puts them one right after the other. How do I put a bit of space in between? I'm very new to html so I'm not sure how to add whitespace, the only way I could think of is to create a  with a specific id that's nothing but an empty block. However, that seems like it's probably a lot of extra code for something relatively simple.

Comment: Use `margins` or _positioning_.

Comment: Is the tables side by side or one beneath the other?

Comment: Your best bet is GOOGLE

Comment: There are many ways to have some spacing between two elements. You'll get some good answers here, so make sure to try them all so you can see which one is best for you.

Comment: You can use multiple <br/> tags.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I fixed the things putting this question on hold...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a gap between the two by setting a margin-top on the second table:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>
            First table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border=1 style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Second table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xweYs/

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! (...for some reason SO isn't letting me accept the answer yet, I will soon though haha)

Comment: @Itay could easily be an answer as well.

Comment: @Itay and what's wrong with this answer ? It seems that this answer helped the OP.

Answer (score 4):

give them some margin.

**CSS:**

```
table
{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```